# Align center on flex item without messing :after

Tags: html, css

How can I vertically align `p` to center without messing `:after` border?
Using `align-items: center;` on `p` doesn't work, and  using it on `.row-flex` messes border

https://jsfiddle.net/rg7rm47w/

```
<div class="row-flex">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <p>
    Title
    <span class="tag">Short tag</span>
  </p>

</div>

.row-flex {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  flex: 1;
}

p {
  flex: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0;
}

p:after {
  width: 50%;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `p` tag ` flex-container column and center as usual.

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6rgh5b19/)

```css
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
}
img {
  flex: 1;
}
p {
  flex: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
p:after {
  width: 50%;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-flex">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <p>
    Title
    <span class="tag">Short tag</span>
  </p>

  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <p>
    Title
    <span class="tag">Short tag</span>
  </p>

</div>

<div class="row-flex">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <p>
    Title
    <span class="parts">Short tag</span>
  </p>

  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <p>
    Title
    <span class="parts">Short tag</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but is it possible for span to be inline? Removing its display: block does nothing, only when I remove  flex-direction: column;

Comment: this breaks while it should be in same line: Title <span class="parts">Short tag</span> https://jsfiddle.net/6rgh5b19/1/